# Proving Inequalities by Mathematical Induction

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm working on this problem $$8^n > (2n-1)^2  \text{ for all } n>2$$
Basis step: $$ 8^3 > [2(3)-1]^2 \text{ is true}$$
Inductive step: Assume P(k) is true,
$$P(k): 8^k > (2k-1)^2$$
$$P(k+1): 8^{k+1}> [2(k+1)-1]^2$$
$$8^{k+1} = 8^k \cdot 8^1 \\>8\cdot(2k-1)^2
\\> 8\cdot(4k^2-4k+1)
$$
I'm lost here and I don't know if I am doing it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $8^k>(2k-1)^2$, then\begin{align}8^{k+1}&=8\times 8^k\\&>8(2k-1)^2\\&=2(4k-2)^2.\end{align}But $4k-2>2k+1$, since this inequality is equivalent to $2k>3$. So,$$8^{k+1}>2(2k+1)^2>\bigl(2(k+1)-1\bigr)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

The function $~\displaystyle f(n) = \frac{2n+1}{2n-1} = 1 + \frac{2}{2n-1}~$ is a decreasing function (as $n$ increases).

$\displaystyle f(3) = \frac{7}{5} < \sqrt{8}.$

Therefore $~\displaystyle \left[f(n)\right]^2 < 8 ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}}.$

As $n$ goes to $(n+1)$ the LHS increases by a factor of $8$, while the RHS increases by a factor of

$$\frac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n-1)^2} = \left[f(n)\right]^2 < 8.$$